# test with arithmetic expansion (leading zero)

Tags: ksh

The following ksh88 code takes values for month [m] and year [y] and works out the previous month [p_m], and year of the previous month [p_m_y].

m is originally derived from date command and so has a leading zero if current month < 10.

```
m=02
y=2017

if [ $((m-1)) -gt 1 ]
then
    p_m=$((m-1))
    p_m_y=$((y))
else
    p_m=12
    p_m_y=$((y-1))
fi
```

In this example p_m is being set to 12, and p_m_y is 2016, so the if statement seems failing and always triggering the 'else' code.... even where m is greater than 1. I think the leading zero may be the issue? The same thing happens if I use [[ .. ]].

If I amend it to the below, it works

```
if [[ $((m-1)) != 01 ]]
```

Presumably this now a string comparison, the arithmetic comparison is not working.  not a huge issue, I could still work with this.

But there should be a way to get it work using proper arithmetic.  If I try and force base10 expansion, it does not have any effect.

```
if [[ $((10#$m-1)) -gt 1 ]]
```

Comment: @Fox You're correct. It should be `if [[ $((m-1)) -gt 0 ]]`

Comment: @Fox I'm not 100% I understand your reply. Does your suggestion `if [ "$m" -gt "1" ]; then` change it into a string comparison? I thought `-gt` was only used for arithmetic calculation in test statements?

Comment: I've deleted my comments and turned them into an answer, complete with a simplification of the overall script

Comment: @fox Thx, I was wondering why you had quoted the "1" in the test statement.

Comment: Consistency.  I quote all the variables in case they become empty, and then quote the other side for consistency.  Rationale: unquoted empty variables go away, causing a syntax error in the test.  Actually, I'd usually do something more like `[ "${m}0" -gt "10" ]`, since some systems ignore even quoted empty arguments.  I don't think that such systems are particularly common though, so I didn't want to get into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in the specific example you show is not that `m` has a leading zero — even if it were treated as octal, `02` is still just `2`.  The test you are using is:

```
[ $((m-1)) -gt 1 ]
```

But `m-1 > 1` is equivalent to `m > 2`.  Since `2` is not greater than `2`, the `else` clause will be run.  You can change the test to simply

```
[ $m -gt 1 ]
```

But it would be far simpler to just use the shell's arithmetic capabilities directly:

```
m=02
y=2017
p_m=$(( (m+10)%12 + 1 ))
p_m_y=$(( y - (m==1) ))
```

That last bit probably merits some explanation:

For `p_m`, we use modular arithmetic.  `(m + 10)%12` is equivalent to "two months prior (or ten months later), except that December is listed as 0".  We then add one to achieve "the previous month, in the range 1–12".

The last line is simpler.  `(m==1)` is either `1` if `m` is numerically equal to 1, else `0`.  So `p_m_y` is set to the current year if `m` is not 1, else the previous year.

---

As an aside, you say:

> m is originally derived from the date command and so has a leading zero if current month < 10.

This is not necessarily the case.  On my system:

```
$ date
2017年  5月  9日 火曜日 13:58:53 EDT
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 date
Tue May  9 13:58:53 EDT 2017
$ date '+%Y %m %d' | sed 's/ 0*/ /g'
2017 5 9
```

So if you are concerned about numbers being interpreted as octal, you may want to try this last one.

Comment: Thank you! I'd never have thought of the modulas arithmetic thing. On my system, `date` returns `Tuesday,  9 May 2017 20:26:25 BST` and `date '+%Y %_m %_d'` returns `2017 %_m %_d`, so it does not support the _m/y options.

Comment: @BenHamilton I don't know if you've seen the latest edit, but I added an option for POSIX `date` after realizing the underscores are a GNU extension.  I'll actually just edit out the GNU-specific line, though — I really hate accidentally advocating non-standard commands

Answer (score 1):

We use the `dc` calculator where the `macro` `a` is called upon when the month is Jan. => prev month => 12 and year is decremented. Othwerise, we just decrement the year.

```
m=01
y=2011

set X `echo "[sa 1- 12]sa $y $m d1- r1- r0 =af" | dc`; shift

p_m=$1  p_m_y=$2

echo "Current month:$m   Current year: $y"
echo "   Prev month:$p_m Prev month year: $p_m_y"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work though, I just tested it in a `ksh` :

```
if [[ $((m-1)) -eq 1 ]]; then echo "Equal"; fi
```

Works with `-gt` too.